# Is the train station of Aiguafreda, Spain ever served?

Tags: spain, national-parks, barcelona, train-stations

While planning a trip, I saw that to access the [Montseny Park](http://parcs.diba.cat/documents/155678/155808/MapaInformadorMontseny.pdf/5a517133-c700-4872-96b1-ef724ab62d11), near Barcelona, one can take a train to the town of Aiguafreda.

However, on [Renfe website](http://www.renfe.com/), the train services website, I cannot find Aiguafreda in the list of stations (nor Figaró, the next town with a station).

Is Aiguafreda served at all by a train (maybe the line was stopped recently)?

Comment: The train station is Sant Martí de Centelles. Aiguafreda is five minutes walking.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The main Renfe website only lists long-distance trains. The line that goes through Aiguafreda is a local line belonging to [Rodalies to Catalunya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodalies_de_Catalunya), operated by the national Renfe but administered by the Catalan government. You can find information about it on the Renfe [Rodalies Barcelona](http://www.renfe.com/EN/viajeros/cercanias/barcelona/index.html) (Barcelona suburbs) web page. The line you want is [R3](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnea_R3), starting in Barcelona with connections with most Metro lines.

The station is not in Aiguafreda but in the adjoining village [Sant Martí de Centelles](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estaci%C3%B3n_de_Sant_Mart%C3%AD_de_Centelles). There is approximately one train per hour (more during morning and evening peak), and the trip from downtown Barcelona is about 50–60 min. The two previous stations on this line, La Garriga and Figaró, are also at the edge of Montseny park.

Comment: Great answer. Clear, concise and full of resources.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it. I can't find a reference anywhere, like you, and even a sample route on [Rome2Rio from Barcelona to Aiguafreda](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Barcelona/Aiguafreda) takes you to Sant Marti de Centelles.

Foursquare also has no comments for the station that I can find, and wikitravel and wikivoyage also only mention it on other pages.

So while it's not a certainty, if it's actually in use, they have a bad image problem to fix...

Comment: Actually, it looks like Sant Marti de Centelles station is 200m from Aiguafreda.

Comment: @Vince yeah, I'm debating whether that's perhaps the NEW station for the town, which would explain the other one being stopped?

Comment: I suppose, or maybe the name of the station just does not match the name of the town (there does not seem  to be any town called Sant Marti de Centelles)

Comment: Wiki claims it's a municipality of sorts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sant_Mart%C3%AD_de_Centelles